# Timeline results contain redundant information?

Tags: discussion, timeline

Can I get a confirmation that the response `/users/{id}/timeline` contains redundant information, namely:

```
 If the action is: | Then the timeline_type is always:
-------------------+----------------------------
  accepted         |   accepted
  asked            |   askedoranswered
  answered         |   askedoranswered
  awarded          |   badge
  comment          |   comment
  revised          |   revision
```

Looking through some API responses, it seems that this is always the case.  If this is true, then why have the `timeline_type` field at all?  It seems like the `action` field contains more descriptive information than the `timeline_type` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more or less redundant.

I'd have to dig back into source control to find exactly why, but I vaguely remember `action` and `timeline_type` diverging late in 1.0 beta.

Expect that route to get some tweaks (more-so perhaps than the typical method) in the 2.0 time frame.